# items misbehaving after using .clone() and forEach()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `.clone()` to move items from one li to another, cloning one is fine, but when I clone multiple items the 2nd 3rd 4th etc of the cloned items will not respond to a click event to add .highlight so I can move them back to the original li if required.

Here is the javaScript there are button controls, functions to add and remove classes and the function to move the li items

```
$("li").on("click", highlighter);
$("#moveright").click(function() {
  moveItems("#leftlist", "#rightlist");
});
$("#moveleft").click(function() {
  moveItemsBack(".highlight", "#leftlist");
});

function highlighter(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "list-group-item") {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
  }
}

function moveItems(origin, destination) {
  var highlighted = document.querySelectorAll(".highlight");
  highlighted.forEach(function(thisObj) {
    $(thisObj).clone(true).appendTo(destination);
    ("#leftlist .highlight").remove();
    setTimeout(removeHighlight, 500);
  });
}

function moveItemsBack(origin, destination) {
  var highlighted = document.querySelectorAll("#rightlist .highlight");
  highlighted.forEach(function(thisObj) {
    $(thisObj).clone(true).appendTo(destination);
    $("#rightlist .highlight").remove();
    setTimeout(removeHighlight, 500);
  });
}

function removeHighlight() {
  $("li").removeClass("highlight");
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<ul id="leftlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">a item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">b item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">c item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">d item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">e item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">f item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">g item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">h item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">i item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">j item</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<ul id="rightlist" class="list-group list-group-flush">
</ul>
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(thisObj).clone(true, true);` if you want to clone the event handlers of all children nodes too.

The first 'True' will copy the current node's event, the second 'True' allowed you to copy all children nodes' event.